# g:select - displaying the value

Tags: html, grails

I have this problem concerning the `<g:select>` tag. I have this statement on my view.gsp,

```
<g:select id='selectedId' name='selectedValue' from='${selectedList}' 
    optionKey='tblColumn' value='${element.value}'/>
```

and having this controller and domain model:

```
// Controller
def element = Model.get(params.id)
render(view:'view.gsp', model:[element: element, selectedList: Value.list()]
// End-Controller

//[Domain Model]: Model
class Model {
   String name
   Value value  
   // constraints
}
//End-[Domain Model]: Model

//[Domain Model]: Value
class Value {
   String tblColumn
   // constraints
   String toString() { "${this.tblColumn}" }
}
//End-[Domain Model]: Value
```

The problem is that I couldn't get the `<g:select>` tag display the value of `${element.value}` as the selected value on the `<selected>` tag once the page is loaded. When I look into the page source code, this code line returns:

```
<select id="selectedId">
   <option value='/* the value by the optionKey */'>/* the value */</option>
   <option value='/* the value by the optionKey*/' selected='selected'>/* the value to be displayed */</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try putting the element method in a curly brackets: def element = {}

Comment: To content of the Controller are inside the closure. Because that part of Controller are part of an if-else condition.